# Crashes not showing in Firebase console after linking from Fabric to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to link my app to firebase so I followed all the steps in this link correctly https://docs.fabric.io/apple/examples/cannonball/index.html and when I force a crash It doesn't show in Firebase console but when I add back `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])`
 it works fine and the crash appears in both fabric and firebase.

I tried also removing api key from info.plist and change run script to `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` still crashes don't appear in firebase nor fabric

Comment: After the force crash, open the application normally (no debugger connected just open the app from the springboard by clicking on it). It will upload the crashlog to the fabric server to be listed in the fabric dashboard.

Comment: It doesn't if I remove the API key from info plist and changed the run script the crash doesn't get reported anywhere.

Comment: All I want to know is using `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` is using fabric api key mandatory to see crashes in firebase

Comment: Are you facing any issues with those two items in your project ?

Comment: Yes they are. @Mohamed Farid

Comment: No I am not, all I know is that fabric is gonna be closed by mid 2019 so I thought I will need to implement firebase crashlytics instead and when I saw the docs there was nothing mentioning fabric api key or `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])`

Comment: So I followed the docs and The link above and it did not work

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. You need keep the Fabric API key present for now.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks a lot Mike. if we shut down fabric it would still be working or we should keep fabric too ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your question.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I am sorry for that, I mean if I closed my fabric account (Shut it down totally) would that affect crashlytics by any means.

Comment: Nope, not at all. You can move to Firebase completely once you're ready.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing, iOS applications migrating from Fabric to the Firebase should follow Fabric integration documentation (not the Firebase Crashlytics documentation).

- Do not remove Fabric keys from Info.plist
- Do not remove `[Fabric with:]` call
- Do run `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` script with arguments (providing old Fabric API Key)

Comment: this works. but does that mean the setup guide of firebase crashlytics is wrong?